# How to filter dataframe with multiple conditions?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, dplyr

I have this dataframe that I'll like to subset (if possible, with `dplyr` or `base R` functions):

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,2,2,2), y = c(30,10,8,10,18,5))

x  y
1 30
1 10
1  8
2 10
2 18
2  5
```

Assuming x are factors (so 2 conditions/levels), how can I subset/filter this dataframe so that I get only `df$y` values that are greater than 15 for `df$x == 1`, and `df$y` values that are greater than 5 for `df$x == 2`?

This is what I'd like to get:

```
df2 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,2), y = c(30,10,18))

x y
1 30
2 10
2 18
```

Appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
with(df, df[ (x==1 & y>15) | (x==2 & y>5), ])
  x  y
1 1 30
4 2 10
5 2 18
```

or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df, (x==1 & y>15) | (x==2 & y>5))
```

Comment: Thanks! The `dplyr` solution works very well. But I don't really understand the `with()` solution. What does the `with()` function do?

Comment: `with` let you use the name of the variable directly, without writing `df$x`. You can do something similar with `attach`.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Now I remember I have used `with` before but forgot about it completely because I hardly use it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

If you have several 'x' groups, one option would be to use `mapply`.  We `split` the 'y' using 'x' as grouping variable, create the vector of values to compare against (`c(15,5)`) and use `mapply` to get the logical index for subsetting the 'df'.

```
df[unlist(mapply('>', split(df$y, df$x), c(15,5))),]
#  x  y
#1 1 30
#4 2 10
#5 2 18
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun! While I prefer the `dplyr` solution above because it's easier to understand, your `mapply` solution is rather neat too, but I don't fully understand how `mapply` works here. Could you explain what `mapply('>', split(df$y, df$x), c(15,5))` means? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @hsl Yes, the `dplyr` and the other solution is neat here.  But, I am selling this ((:-) for large number of groups, ie. if you have say 100 x unique values, and there are 100 values to compare with `y` elements for each 'x', then, the `mapply` will compare the corresponding list element (output of `split`) with the corresponding vector element (`c(15,5)`) using the `>`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I was playing with the code and realised this method doesn't seem to work if there are different numbers of each 'x' value, say `data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2), y = c(30,10,8,10,18,5,9))` (three 1s and four 2s). Is this because for this to work, `mapply` has to return a dataframe, rather than list? @akrun

Comment: @hsl You have to use `unlist`.  I think it works for most cases. `df[unlist(mapply('>', split(df$y, df$x), c(15,5))),]`  In the example provided, the lengths were equal, so the `mapply` coerced the results to `matrix`, while here it stayed as `list`.  So, better use `unlist`