# R: How do I filter a data frame with multiple conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm using the following dataset: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Public-Safety/NYPD-Arrests-Data-Historic-/8h9b-rp9u

I extracted the dates so I have 3 columns: `ARREST_YEAR`, `ARREST_MONTH`, `ARREST_DAY`

I want to filter this data frame such that I only get results for when `ARREST_YEAR` = 2006.

I also want to filter for the `ARREST_YEAR` = 2006 and `KY_CD` = 235

I searched and I found this [How to filter dataframe with multiple conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037199/how-to-filter-dataframe-with-multiple-conditions) but my code isn't working using `plyr`: `filter(nyc_crime2, ("ARREST_YEAR" == 2006 & "KY_CD" == 235))`

Comment: If you're using `dplyr`, you don't quote the column names. `filter(nyc_crime2, ARREST_YEAR == 2006 & KY_CD == 235)`

Comment: I used `plyr` and I get an error without the quotes: object 'ARREST_YEAR` not found but I don't get that error with quotes.

Comment: `plyr` doesn't have a function named `filter`. Maybe you have some other package that has a `filter` function? There are several, but the `dplyr` version is the one you want. Try `dplyr::filter(nyc_crime2, ARREST_YEAR == 2006 & KY_CD == 235)`

Comment: Also mind your column names... say you have a column named `Year`, but your code use `ARREST_YEAR`. Make sure you use the right name, and capitalization matters.

Comment: I installed `dplyer` and it still doesn't work. It's actually `ARREST_YEAR`. My mistake.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean now? Error, warning, wrong result, no result, R crashes....? Could you verify that `dplyr` works in general? Try `library(dplyr)` and then `filter(mtcars, cyl == 4 & gear == 5)`. Do you see two rows of data? If not, what happens and what do you see?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/TBdXCSp.png https://i.imgur.com/lYjtCN4.png

Comment: I ended up restarting R and then reinstalling dplyr. It is working now and as you stated, the column names should not be in quotes when using dplyr: https://i.imgur.com/pizanZ8.png  https://i.imgur.com/UkNPnhM.png Thanks

Comment: Yeah, the "time series" stuff in your first attempt makes it seem like you converted the data frame to a time series object that `dplyr` didn't know what to do with.