# How to pull out columns in r based on various criteria

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a huge data.set in R (1mil+ rows) and 51 columns. One of my columns is "StateFIPS" the other is "CountyFIPS" and another is "event type". The rest I do not care about.
Is there an easy way to take that dataframe and pull out all the columns that have "StateFIPS"=3 AND "CountyFIPS=4" AND "event type"=Tornado, and put all those rows into a new dataframe.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean pull out all the rows with those 3, 4 and Tornado conditions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter dataframe with multiple conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037199/how-to-filter-dataframe-with-multiple-conditions)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `subset`

```
df2 <- subset(df1, StateFIPS == 3 & CountyFIPS == 4 & `event type` == "Tornado")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure,

You can sue the `which()` command, see https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/which

You can then use any logical conditions (and combine them with `&` (=and) and `|` (=or)

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy. This should do it (supposing your data.frame is named "data_set")

```
new_data <- data_set[(data_set$CountyFIPS == 4) |
                     (data_set$event_type == 'Tornado') |
                     (data_set$StateFIPS == 3),]
```